# $_FILES is not empty but move_uploaded_file returns false

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a problem. Since hours I try to get a upload script working. I also read some other questions on stackoverflow but nothing helped. The webspace allows file_upload and the size of the file is not too large. The directory where to move the downloads exists, too.
My html code is:

```
Upload: <input type="file" name="file">
```

And my PHP code is:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $name_file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/" . $name_file);
}
```

I echoed $_FILES and the file was in there and there was no error. Everytime I try to upload the file (I also tried to upload other files and file types) move_uploaded_file returned false.

EDIT: The folder is writeable now.

Comment: Are you sure that `upload/` exists and is writeable?

Comment: Yes the folder exists and the permissions are 755. I think that these are the right permissions.

Comment: you can add this before move_uploaded_file(): `if(!is_writable("upload") || !is_dir("upload")){ echo "error in dir"; }`

Comment: if you check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) you will read that **If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE**. Just check your uploading folder permissions.

Comment: Double check that it is writable by running `is_writable()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: `is_writable()` return false and `is_dir()` returns true. The dir-permissions are 755. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, permissions should be 666.

Comment: Okay, I updated the permissions but the file does not get moved...

Comment: And what does `is_writable()` return?

Comment: Then I'm afraid that the problem must lie somewhere else...

Comment: Any ideas? I'm clueless... :(

Comment: What type of file are you uploading? Have you tried uploading to a different directory, or `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/ahardcodedfilename.yourext);` where `yourext` is the extension of the file you are uploading? Just trying to help you identify the issue.

Comment: I'm uploading .zip and .rar files. I'll try it.

Comment: Nope. Another directory does not work (it is writable) and a hardcoded filename does not work, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem. I enabled `error_resporting()` and because any reason the permissions weren't set. Now they are 777 and I can move the files.

Answer (score 3):

Folder upload will not writable by others by setting permission 755. You may set permission atleast 666 through chmod command or better set ownership for upload folder for apache user.

I setup it On Ubuntu like that

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data upload
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the folder permissions on `upload` to `666`. This should ensure that the directory is correctly writeable.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may help someone.

I met the same problem, my `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` has proper returns while `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$destination_dir)` returns nothing. So I ran this check:

```
if(!is_writable($destination_dir)){ echo "error in dir"; }
```

and got the message "error in dir". Even my `$destination_dir` in `move_uploaded_file` has been set to 777. After spending a long time searching, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343809/php-is-writable-function-always-returns-false-for-a-writable-directory). So these two commands solved my problem:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 Ad_images/
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t Ad_images/
```

Now the `is_writable($destination_dir)` returns 1 and the uploading is successful.

**TL;DR:
Make sure your destination directory is writable for php.**