# PHP is_writable() function always returns false for a writable directory

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, redhat, rhel7

I'm trying to install a PHP-based [software package](https://www.limesurvey.org/) in a Red Hat 7 Amazon EC2 instance (ami-8cff51fb) that has had Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 5.4.16 installed on it using yum. The installation fails because it says a particular directory needs to be writable by the webserver with 0755 or 0775 permissions.

The directory in question has 0775 permissions with `root:apache` ownership. I have verified that the httpd process is being run by the apache user and that the apache user is a member of the apache group.

If I edit `/etc/passwd` to temporarily give the apache user a login shell and then `su` to that account, I am able to manually create files as the apache user within the directory using the `touch` command.

I took a look at the source code of the installer script and identified that it's failing because PHP's `is_writable()` function is returning false for the directory in question. I created a separate test PHP script to isolate and verify the behaviour I'm seeing:

```
<?php
  $dir = '/var/www/html/limesurvey/tmp';
  if (is_writable($dir)) {
    echo $dir, ' is writable';
  } else {
    echo $dir, ' is NOT writable';
  }
?>
```

This outputs the NOT writable message. If I change `$dir` above to be `/tmp` then it correctly outputs that `/tmp` is writable.

If I change the directory permissions to 0777 and/or change the ownership to `apache:apache` then PHP still reports that the directory isn't writable. I even tried creating a `/test` directory set up with the same permissions and ownership and my test script still reports it as not writable.

I'm really at a loss as to explain this behaviour, so any ideas would be welcome!

Thanks in advance.

---

The directory listing for `/var/www/html/limesurvey` is given below. The `tmp` and `upload` directories have 0775 permissions as per Lime Survey's [installation instructions](https://manual.limesurvey.org/Installation). `test.php` is my test script mentioned above.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-x-x-xxx limesurvey]$ pwd
/var/www/html/limesurvey
[ec2-user@ip-xx-x-x-xxx limesurvey]$ ls -al
total 80
drwxr-xr-x. 20 root apache 4096 Mar 30 11:25 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     23 Mar 25 14:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root apache   38 Mar 10 12:56 admin
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 application
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 docs
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 fonts
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 framework
-rw-r--r--.  1 root apache  429 Mar 10 12:56 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--.  1 root apache  399 Mar 10 12:56 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--.  1 root apache  296 Mar 10 12:56 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 images
-rw-r--r--.  1 root apache 6652 Mar 10 12:56 index.php
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root apache   39 Mar 10 12:56 installer
drwxr-xr-x. 89 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 locale
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root apache   39 Mar 25 14:41 logs
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root apache   49 Mar 10 12:56 plugins
-rw-r--r--.  1 root apache   61 Mar 10 12:56 README
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 scripts
-rw-r--r--.  1 root apache  380 Mar 10 12:56 .scrutinizer.yml
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 styles
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 styles-public
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 templates
-rw-r--r--.  1 root apache  159 Mar 30 11:11 test.php
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root apache   20 Mar 10 12:56 themes
drwxr-xr-x. 26 root apache 4096 Mar 10 12:56 third_party
drwxrwxr-x.  5 root apache   80 Mar 26 13:45 tmp
drwxrwxr-x.  6 root apache   79 Mar 10 12:57 upload
```

Running `namei -l /var/www/html/limesurvey/tmp` gives:

```
[ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-xxx ~]$ namei -l /var/www/html/limesurvey/tmp
f: /var/www/html/limesurvey/tmp
drwxr-xr-x root root   /
drwxr-xr-x root root   var
drwxr-xr-x root root   www
drwxr-xr-x root root   html
drwxr-xr-x root apache limesurvey
drwxrwxr-x root apache tmp
```

Comment: This might be a silly question, but have you verified that the directory exists?

Comment: @Flosculus Not a silly question at all, but yes, the directory definitely exists.

Comment: I implemented your `/test` directory example with `0777`, used your code and it worked fine.  Could you print out the `ls -al` for that directory please?

Comment: @Flosculus I've edited the question to include the directory listing.

Comment: For clarify, can you run this in your PHP test file: `exec('whoami', $output); print_r($output);`, or even better `exec('id', $output);`.  Compare against the system's list of users and verify that the user being run as apache is real.

Comment: what happens when you `touch` from php ?

Comment: @Flosculus `echo exec('id', $output)` returns `uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache) context=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0` - looking at `/etc/group`, it has `apache:x:48:apache`.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas as well, only thing I can think of is how despite having write permissions on the directory, those same permissions might not extend to its contents, this should be covered by ACL, issues are listed in the comments: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: @exussum PHP's `touch` function returned false when I tried to use it to create a file in the directory.

Comment: just as an idea, who owns the file if you write to /tmp with php ?

Comment: @exussum I tried using the PHP `touch` function to create a file in `/tmp`. It actually ended up in `/tmp/systemd-private-dWqSkg/tmp` with apache as the owner and group.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After much head-scratching, it transpired that SELinux was preventing the directory from being written to. I found a [good tutorial that explains what's going on](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/). I was able to fix it by running this command:

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t tmp
```

Answer (score 13):

in **CentOS** 6 above should be **SELinux** enable enforcing

```
setenforce Permissive
```

check the status

```
sestatus
```

refer to https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: Thanks a bunch for pointing out the problem (SELinux) on CentOS. However, this solution seems to be temporary as per the wiki. A better on would be running `setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs=1` (referring to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98740)).

Answer (score 0):

to write to a directory you also need execute permissions to the dirs above.

```
namei -l /var/www/html/limesurvey/tmp
```

should show which step you do not have the correct permissions for.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the `namei` output. As you can see, the entire directory tree has owner and group execute permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX tmp
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX tmp
```

Taken directly from the Symfony2 installation guide, this solves the problem with cache write access sharing between Apache and CLI tools.  This might work for your `tmp` directory as well.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that (and restarted the Apache service), but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

is_writable by default only checks on the user, not the group.
So even if you group is matching and has permissions is_writable will return false.
To relax this check you will need to set

```
safe_mode_gid = On
```

in the PHP config or change the user accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php), that option was removed in PHP 5.4.0. I'm using PHP 5.4.16.