# fopen return false but directory exists

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a local file using mpdf->Output() that eventually goes down to fopen() with `wb` as the mode.

the request always returns an error since the fopen returs false.

the folder exists with full permissions and event tried with checking the folder with is_dir and is_exists.

nothing work, and using relative and absolute path changes nothing.

the funny thing that on my local machine (windows) everything works fine and the file is saved.

the saving code:

```
$tmpPath = 'eventInfoFiles/EventInfo' . $reg->id . '.pdf';

$pdf->Output($tmpPath, 'F');
```

this is the erro message:

> Invalid request - Server Error (1): Error 500: error: Unable to create output file: /var/www/html/youth-movements/api/eventInfoFiles/EventInfo207724.pdf file : /var/www/html/youth-movements/api/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php line : 9443

the permissions from my server. file is located at the root of the project

```
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root root     6 Jul  1 10:01 eventInfoFiles
```

Comment: What is “file is located at the root of the project” supposed to mean? You mean the _folder_ `eventInfoFiles`? And what do you actually consider the root of the project here?

Comment: the folder is located inside api folder (as stated in the error itself),full path is :/var/www/html/youth-movements/api (this is considered the project root folder

Comment: _“(as stated in the error itself)”_ - the error message states where it _couldn’t_ create the file only, we can not deduce whether the path is correct or not to begin with from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`is_writable()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php):

```
$path= 'eventInfoFiles/EventInfo' . $reg->id . '.pdf';
if(is_writable($path)) {
    $pdf->Output($tmpPath, 'F');
} else  {
    ...
}
```

Comment: tried it already, didn't fixed the issue

Comment: Isn't it usually the `www-data` group/user Apache runs on?

Comment: The username varies a lot ...may also be `www`.

Comment: it's not the issue since i have a similar logic in another folder, that saves to another folder in the root directory with the same mpdf->Output(), and it works just fine. the second folder has the same permissions

Comment: the is_writable gave me the insight for fixing it. needed sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t tmp. found it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343809/php-is-writable-function-always-returns-false-for-a-writable-directory. can you please edit the answer for future use. thanks

Comment: You didn't tell which Linux distribution you were using.